# Automated aligning audio tracks with timings for dubbing screen casts

Tags: video, editing, screen-casting, tracks, audio

We have some screen casts that need to be dubbed to various languages for which we have script for the target language like:

```
Begining Time | Audio Narration

0:0           | blah nao lorep iposm...

1:20          | aqzao dok dkjv  dwv....

...
```

We can record each of the above units separately and then align it at the proper beginning times as mentioned in the above script.
Is there a tool or system which allows us to align these audio units based on the times provided?

**EXAMPLE**:

**Input:**

Input the `N` time values: `0:0,1:20 ...`
Then input the `N` audio recordings.

**Output:**

Audio recordings aligned to the above timings while:

- Overflow should be detected by the system individually
- Underflow is padded by silence

Comment: If there was a solution, it would probably have been pretty well known, because you'll need to make a program that can partially transcribe speech in many languages, which is a huge project.

Comment: I find it very simple thing to do and can become a plugin to audacity

Comment: For a human, yes, but for a programmer no. If I've understood you correctly, you provide a transcription file that tells the plugin what text should be played when. The problem is that you need an advanced program to be able to figure out what is said in each clip. You have a coordinate system with x seconds. And y is the position of the microphone membrane. And then you have if's and else's and loops to figure out what is spoken. It's a huge project, and how many programs like that work in any language other than english? Not many, so it's a big project, so IF this kind of plugin existed, it

Comment: would be well known.

Comment: No you got it wrong, I dont want that , please read the question carefully , its  a simple system that Inputs N recordings and N timings and outputs a single time aligned file  @FriendofKim

Comment: Okay, but what then is the problem?

Comment: You can just use a program like Adobe Premiere Pro, easy and fast. If you don't know how to do it, I can post an answer :)

Comment: Did you understand that it would be helpful to dub in many languages?. I can see it to be a simple programming Job, before doing it myslef was checking about existing solutions

Comment: Yes, if you use Premiere Pro, it's a breeze. I can show you if you want.

Comment: Sure do show me , I mean can we input N timing values and N recordings to get them aligned into a single file?

Comment: There we go. Good luck :)

Comment: Linux command line solution might be acceptable?

Comment: sure it would be ! @EugeneS

Comment: @EugeneS Infact a commandline solution would be the best solution

Comment: This question has an open bounty worth +100 reputation from wordtext ending in 22 hours. @EugeneS

Comment: Yep. I've noticed. Trying to think something out using `cuebreakpoints` and `shnsplit`. No luck yet though..

Comment: I guess a simple perl\python script can do the JOB

Comment: @EugeneS ANY LUCK?

Comment: Unfortunately, couldn't work it out..

Answer (score 1):

Add your video to your timeline. Then you play the video from the beginning. Now you are going to insert a marker every time you want a new clip to be inserted. If you have CS6, the shortcut is M, otherwise it's * on the numpad.

When you've added all the markers, you should delete the video track (since you only want the audio. If you want to render the video with the dub directly from Premiere Pro, just delete the audio.)

Then you import all the audio files you want. Be sure to name them alphabetically so that Premiere knows which order to place them in. Then you have to make sure that the Project pane is selected. Then you go to the menu and choose Project->Automate to Sequence... Choose Sort order and At Unnumbered Markers. Now they will be placed one by one at the markers you've placed. If one audio clip is too long , it'll just be clipped where the next one starts.

Hopefully this will solve your problem. Now, you can use the same markers for every language you are dubbing.

Good luck! :)

Comment: I dont have adobe premiere but I dont see any way to input timing values, this is must for me

Comment: and its waste of time to name it alphabetically too more ever I have to place the markers manually , I want it to be aligned to the timings I input

Comment: Yes, and you input those markers easily by pressing M on your keyboard. And then this becomes the template you can use for every language. Set up the markers once, and then you're done for that one movie.

Comment: After what you have explained, this is a perfect solution to your problem, and if it is not, you have to describe your problem more carefully.

Comment: No  I want to input the timings directly like copy pasting it , not even PRESSING M each time, Its all about mass poduction

Comment: e.G: 0.12,2.15,3.3,4.3 etc would be input and then align them as simple as that. I saw the demo of adobe its too bloated and overloaded for this task

Comment: Well, if you don't want to accomplish your task, that's too bad for you. I gave you a working solution to easily align the dubbed material with the actual video. The only difference is that you need to press M to set it up. You have to name them alphabetically no matter what you do...